# Python script makes a file but doesn't write anything

Tags: python

First, code gets a name and makes a file with `w` permission (also tested  `r+`) and it should write any other input in file, but it doesn't. I get an empty file.

```
user_name_in =input("gets Input")
fname = user_name_in
f = input()
ufile = open(fname,"w")
while True:
    f=input(answer)
    ufile.write(f)
```

Comment: Have you tried `with open(fname, 'w') as ufile: ufile.write(f)` ?

Comment: Add `ufile.close()` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Rawing you would still have to `flush` the file. always use the `with` to handle files.

Comment: @Rawing Tested , still no content in result file

Comment: @MohammadHoseinBin Did you add it at the very end outside the loop? Also, have something that terminates the loop so it can reach the end

Comment: What is `answer`? Have you defined that elsewhere? If not your script will raise a `NameError` exception and terminate without writing to the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i wrote in the comments, always use the `with` block to handle files as it takes care of intricacies you don't have to worry about. Now on the code, you repeat yourself, for example the first two lines are actually one.. This is what it would look when cleaned a bit.

```
fname = input("gets Input")
with open(fname, "w") as ufile:
    f = input('write something')
    ufile.write(f)
```

And as others also noticed, the `answer` is never declared, there is no termination condition and the input prompts are either not the best or totally absent.

Comment: Answer is declared somewhere else , I declared it externally in String management part of program.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
user_name_in =input("gets Input")
fname = user_name_in
f = input()
ufile = open(fname,"w")
while True:
    f=input(answer)
    ufile.write(f)
```

Some considerations:
I don't see where *answer* is declared, neither python interpreter see :P, maybe you forgot to paste this part of the code or indeed this was the error?

I don't understand why you assign the name of the file to a variable and then re-assign to another one.

How do I stop writing to the file? The only way I found was Ctrl-C, which doesn't sound ideal.

To reassure the file is being closed you can replace it with a **with open(fname) as ufile** block

Comment: f variable got same use and in optimized final code will be fixed. there are if's in while that'll break the loop. i just placed only necessary parts of Code